# QCacheGrind source code path wrong

Tags: xdebug, cachegrind

Trying to profile my code with QCacheGrind and everything loads fine but I can't see the source code inside the program.

For some reason the source code path is wrong.

Right now it is `cachegrind file location` + `php file location`

It should be only `php file location`

[image: source code error]

Comment: What does the cachegrind file itself say? Does that have just the (correct) php file location in it?

Comment: The filenames inside cachegrind are like that: `C:\wamp\www\petka\php-activerecord\lib\Singleton.php`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in QCacheGrind then. Send them a bug report?

Answer (score 4):

This is a cachegrind bug that appears under non-linux filesystems.

Cachegrind will look for source files in the path where your callgrind output file is, appended to the path where your Source file is (this path is stored in the callgrind output).
C:/callgrind/C:/Project/src/index.php

You can work around this bug by placing your callgrind outputs in a folder directly outside your source root ( C:/Project/ ). And running a replace on your callgrind output file to delete the directory of your callgrind output from all of the source file paths, thus the callgrind output will show that your source file is at src/index.php .

In the end, cachegrind will join C:/Project/ and src/index.php and you will be able to view your source code in cachegrind.

Comment: Note from the future: A more permanent solution is to stop using php.

Comment: PHP is not going anywhere any time soon. COBOL and FORTRAN are still around and PHP powers about 80% of websites around the world.

Comment: Note from the future: PHP is still here

Comment: Note from the future: Running tools in their native OS will reduce the likelihood of encountering bugs.